# Converting between little endian and big endian values stored in a std::vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++, c++17, endianness

Currently I am using a vector of `uint8_t`'s in order to represent some binary data.  Sometimes I also use this format in order to send integers and longs and some other types over the wire. And while I can use

```
__builtin_bswap16(littleEndianValue);
__builtin_bswap32(littleEndianValue);
__builtin_bswap64(littleEndianValue);
```

or

```
htonl
```

I am curious if there is any disadvantage of using the `std::reverse` method of the vector i.e. like that:

```
std::reverse(std::begin(theVectorBuffer), std::end(theVectorBuffer));
```

since that does not require me to

1. extract the actual integers value from the vector
2. apply `__builtin_bswap32`
3. putting those integers back to the vector

Basically I am trying to save some constructor calls as well as some memory allocations. I have not measured this solution yet, but I was hoping that someone can think of reason why *not* to use the `std::reverse` method and stop me from doing something stupid. I am afraid that this will have some negative effect in the future that I can not predict yet. I am willing to use the `std::reverse` method only in the parts of the code where I know the type and the length of the vector (for example when holding `uint64_t`). Those vectors are used later on to be concatenated and send over the wire in a TCP connection.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the question in reverse: Whats the disadvantage of using the methods designed to swap endianess? They will be atleast as fast as `std::reverse` but very likely alot faster. If your already know that you have a `std::uint64_t` you can call them without problems, if you don' you cant call `std::reverse` because that would corrupt the data.

Comment: Think about it: Your relying on the compiler to optimize the `std::reverse` call when you could actually operate with a 100% gurantee on a 64bit int instead of single bytes with potential overhead.

Comment: Finally, if your in doubt, measure it.

Comment: Changing vector afterward seems strange: reversing should be done by part (2 uint16:`[0x1234, 0x5678]` should result into `[0x4321, 0x8765]` and not `[0x8765, 0x4321]`) that require to know afterward content of array whereas it might be fed directly with correct value. In addition `hton` family might do noop when already in good format, and changing is not necessary reverse order, some architecture are more special.

Comment: Sebastian, thanks i guess i will have to measure it first before moving on. I do not want to take any chances. I am Cristal clear aware that __builtin_bswap16 would be much faster then std::reverse , nor doubght about that. however what i was hoping to gain on speed was those other calls which are related to extracting integers from the buffer  converting them and putting them back in the buffer.  But as you mentioned no way around measuring it.  I was hoping that someone tried doing that before and said been there done that (bad idea because of ...).

Comment: @Jarod42 as mentioned i am intending to use this only on vector of uint8_t and thus shorts do not come into question. And only there where i know the type and the size/length of that type in advanced. But you are completely right about your point if using different types other then using8_t. Thank you!

Comment: I mean `uint8_t` is single byte, so no endianess issues. But those bytes might represent other data (such as uin16_t in my example). And for each those data you have to do the conversion. reversing whole vector won't work (except if you only have one field)